# Why does BeautifulSoup return a NoteType value, even when the element is there?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape thumbnail images from a website, but when I request BS to find a specific div class, it returns NONE. I tried this before on a similar website and I managed to to get everything within the desired div class but i'm running into issues here. If you have the time I would be extremely grateful for your advice.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
from pickle import NONE, TRUE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests.exceptions


localfile = "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/TapTap Apps/TapTap Page 1"
url = "https://www.taptap.cn/app/"
username = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
proxy = f"https://{username}:{password}@someproxysite.com"

def webScraper(url, proxy, min, max):
    for x in range(min, max):
        page = requests.get(url + str(x), proxy, timeout=10)                                # Request url and iterate with x
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
        image = soup.find('div', class_="tap-image-wrapper app-info-board__img")            # Finds the HTML elements that holds the image
        print (image)

webScraper(url, proxy, 12332, 13000)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `div` with that exact class, or a `div` with at least one of two space-separate class names?

Comment: Yes. I was looking for a div with that exact class. It has the thumbnail image and the title that I needed.

Comment: So you have something `<div class="tap-image-wrapper app-info-board__img">`? AFAIK, that's not one single class name, but two separate classes `tap-image-wrapper` and `app-info-board__img`. See https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-by-css-class.

Comment: No you're absolutely right! They are two seperate classes. I figured that my isssues is in ttrying to any div with both classes and had to choose between using either request.get() or import HTML Sessions and use sessions.get().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy configuration is wrong for starters, it should be passed as a dictionary instead.

```
proxies = {"https": proxy}
page = requests.get(url + str(x), proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
```

Also in request you can specify the user agent you can try for any but for example for chrome its

```
user_agent_det = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent_det}
page = requests.get(url + str(x), headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
```

And to get the image

```
def webScraper(url, proxy, min, max):
    proxies = {"https": proxy}
    user_agent_det = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent_det}

    for x in range(min, max):
        try:
            page = requests.get(url + str(x), , headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
            if page.status_code == 200:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
                image = soup.find('div', class_="tap-image-wrapper app-info-board__img")
                print(image)
            else:
                print(f"Failed to access {url} : {page.status_code}")
        except Exception  as e:
            print(f"Failed : {e}")
```

Comment: Sorry! I should have set my proxies as a dictionary but beacuse  they were provided from a proxy service site, I wasn't quite sure how to implement it. But Thank you so much for your help! I didn't think to run my function as an if else statement inside a try except clause.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your code may be causing issues. Let's explore some improvements:

1. **Proxy Handling:** Fix how proxies are managed in your code. Use the `proxies` parameter in `requests.get()` instead of embedding proxy details in the URL. Also, handle cases where no proxy is needed.
2. **User-Agent Header:** Some websites may block requests without a proper User-Agent header. Add a User-Agent header to mimic a web browser.
3. **Check for Element Existence:** It's good practice to check if an element exists before trying to access its properties.

In this refined version of your code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

localfile = "C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/TapTap Apps/TapTap Page 1"
url = "https://www.taptap.cn/app/"
username = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
proxy = {"http": f"http://{username}:{password}@someproxysite.com", "https": f"https://{username}:{password}@someproxysite.com"}

def webScraper(url, proxy, min, max):
    for x in range(min, max):
        page = requests.get(url + str(x), proxies=proxy, timeout=10, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"})
        
        if page.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
            image = soup.find('div', class_="tap-image-wrapper app-info-board__img")
            
            if image:
                print(image)
            else:
                print(f"No image found for {url}{x}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch {url}{x}. Status code: {page.status_code}")

webScraper(url, proxy, 12332, 13000)
```

Make sure to replace the User-Agent string based on your requirements. Also, exercise caution regarding website terms of service concerning web scraping practices.

Comment: I really appreciate the advice, thank you so much!